# Playback authentication for RTSP (vods3)

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'm facing an issue while setting RTP/Authentication/PlayMethod to "basic" for my vods3 application. As soon as I make the change, restart WOWZA, and then go the streaming engine manager, the option "RTSP/RTP" in playback type is disabled.

My goal is to have authenticated playback through RTSP. Any help is appreciated

Here's the section of my Application.xml:

Thanks in advance.

```
<RTP>
<!-- RTP/Authentication/[type]Methods defined in Authentication.xml. Default setup includes; none, basic, digest -->
    <Authentication>
            <PublishMethod>block</PublishMethod>
            <PlayMethod>basic</PlayMethod>
    </Authentication>
    <!-- RTP/AVSyncMethod. Valid values are: senderreport, systemclock, rtptimecode -->
    <AVSyncMethod>senderreport</AVSyncMethod>
    <MaxRTCPWaitTime>12000</MaxRTCPWaitTime>
    <IdleFrequency>75</IdleFrequency>
    <RTSPSessionTimeout>90000</RTSPSessionTimeout>
    <RTSPMaximumPendingWriteBytes>0</RTSPMaximumPendingWriteBytes>
    <RTSPBindIpAddress></RTSPBindIpAddress>
    <RTSPConnectionIpAddress>0.0.0.0</RTSPConnectionIpAddress>
    <RTSPOriginIpAddress>127.0.0.1</RTSPOriginIpAddress>
    <IncomingDatagramPortRanges>*</IncomingDatagramPortRanges>
    <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/RTP.xml for any depacketizers loaded by this application -->
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
 </RTP>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the response at WOWZA forum:

https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?49259-Problem-with-playmethod-quot-Basic-quot-and-RTSP-(vods3)&p=163751#post163751